# Jest focus() is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, stenciljs

Here is my file which have button to read more and this button sets focus on  element

**Component**

```
 ...
 handleFocusOnText = (): void => {
  setTimeout(() => this.hiddenTextRef?.focus(), 500)
 }
...
rednder()
...
<span ref={(el) => (this.hiddenTextRef = el)} tabIndex={-1} innerHTML={hiddenContent} />

<button
 data-qa="readmore-expander-button"
 onClick={this.handleClick}
 >
 {this.isOpen ? this.labelLess : this.labelMore}
 </button>
```

handleClick method is also calling handleFocusOnText.

Problem is that i call click on this button in my test file and its throwing TS error that focus from *handleFocusOnText* is not a function. Can you help me out of this issue?

***Test.spec.ts***

```
 ....
// Click "read more" button
page.doc.querySelector('button').click()

await page.waitForChanges()
const spanEl = document.querySelector('[data-qa="test-span"]')

expect(spanEl).not.toBeNull()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder this is not getting right context - how about changing

```
onClick={this.handleClick}
```

to

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
```

would that work?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this does not help. click function works great. The issue is in the test file which is calling some handling from click and the focus does not exist - most probably component is not initialized.